# Ng-repeat commenting itself out in Jade template (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug

first time asking a question on this site, but I hope I can get some help. I am new to angular / jade and making a for fun project to learn it.

Whenever I attempt to ng-repeat its getting commented out. I have been researching this and trying to figure out the issue for the past few hours but having trouble figuring this out, and there are no error messages. I will include relevant files below

my Index.jade
extends layout

```
block content
    +mediasection()
    input(type="text" data-ng-model="test")
    | {{test}}
```

My mediasection.jade
`mixin mediasection()
    div.media-section
        +medianav()
        div.media-block(ng-repeat="item in media | orderBy:mediaOrder ")
            ul
                li
                    | {{item.name}}`

My controller.js

```
var mediaController = angular.module('mediaController', []);

mediaController.controller('mediaListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/data.json").success(function(data){
        $scope.media = data;
        $scope.mediaOrder = 'name';
        console.log('got media!');
    });
}]);
```

and finally my app

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'mediaController'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
        controller: 'mediaListController'
    });
}]);
```

Thank you very much before hand :)

Comment: what does data.json look like? If it is proper json and your request headers are incorrect (i.e. the accept header is something other than application/json) you may be receiving the response as a string, in which case ngRepeat wouldn't work because it expects media to be an array

Comment: @ruedamanuel There is a lot of text to it, but most of it is copied and pasted from itself. I validated it and it said it was valid. Here is the first 7 lines from it, is there supposed to be something at the beginning of the json document that I didnt know?

[
 {
  "name": "Lorem iipsum",
  "para": "rjojregojegjoioiergoigoioijgr",
  "img": "1.jpg",
  "section": "music"
 },

Any issues you see?

Comment: the headers aren't part of the content (if that's what you meant by "something at the beginning of the document"), they're part of the HTTP request and response. try logging the typeof of the response in the success handler. if it says "string" then you will need to parse the response as JSON or change the headers